# Invalid email when resetting password on Parse.com (JS SDK)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework, password-recovery

I am trying to reset password on my angularjs App. I am using Parse (js SDK) as a backend.
I am using Parse.User.requestPasswordReset as said in the doc, but I am always getting an error 125 invalid email address.

Here is my html form :

```
<input type="email" ng-model="resetData.email" required>
<button ng-click="resetPassword(resetData)">
    Ok
</button>
```

Here is my controller :

```
app.controller('userCtrl', function($scope, loginService){
    $scope.resetPassword = function(resetData){
        loginService.resetPassword(resetData,$scope);
    };
});
```

And finally here is my factory :

```
app.factory('loginService', function(){
    return{
        resetPassword:function(resetData,scope){
            console.log(resetData.email);
            Parse.User.requestPasswordReset(resetData.email,{
                success:function(){
                    alert('You'll receive an email to reset your password');
                },
                error:function(error){
                    if (error.code === 205) {
                        scope.msg_erreur='User not found';
                        console.log("error "+error.code+" "+error.message);
                    }
                    else{
                        scope.msg_erreur='Oops ! Something wrong happened';
                        console.log("error "+error.code+" "+error.message);
                    };
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Good to know :

- the console.log(resetData.email) show the good email address.
- the email address I used are really in the User Class (if not there is an "error 205 user not found")
- I tried to put an email address directly in my code in the Parse.User.requestPasswordReset instead of resetData.email
- I tried with several email address, all are real ones.

In every case I always have this error 125 invalid email address.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are storing the email address in the `username` field, and letting users login that way. Put the email address in the `email` field as well and the reset email should go out as expected.

This seems to be an issue with the way Parse is dealing with resets, because this was not a problem before. This workaround is not elegant, but it will work until the issue is properly resolved from their end.